# Intent recognition from LUIS in a Cortana bot not working via REST API

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, cortana

I'm integrating a service written in a language other than Node and C# with the MS Bot Framework, so I'm just using the REST API to interact with the Bot Framework. I also have a LUIS app that I'd like to use for intent recognition.

I've connected my LUIS app to my bot on the Settings page, but requests from Cortana (other than the opening `Microsoft.Launch` intent) are coming in under the `None` intent despite LUIS classifying them correctly in its own dashboard.

I'm already annoyed that in order to respond to a POST from Cortana, I have to send a POST of my own, but please tell me it isn't the case that I have to POST the text to LUIS myself as well in order to get each intent classified. Is that what the .NET SDK is doing under the hood?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code that causes the issue. What is this super-secret "language other than Node and C#"?

Comment: You might be interested in reading any blog article other than [this one](https://trycatch.blog/2017/03/26/conversational-interfaces-101-writing-a-chatbot-in-java-with-microsoft-bot-api/)

Comment: have you trained your LUIS model and published?

Comment: Responses to the comments I have so far (in order):

1) It's not my code that I'm having trouble with; it's the requests my server is receiving (they come in with the text filled in, but the intent is set to `None` even though the same text passed through the LUIS app gets properly classified). I'm working in Python, but that's inconsequential here.

2) Yes; I've trained and published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else tries to search SO before reading the MS SDK code, I regret to inform you that the answer is (currently) yes: the MS Node SDK [makes an HTTPS GET](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/384a12372db00cb9ef18647bf3e15a8b50c20d6b/Node/core/src/dialogs/LuisRecognizer.ts#L117) to LUIS to classify intents.

Note that that link is to a specific blob on GitHub; the library is of course subject to change.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16746907)

Comment: In this case, if the link (which is to a line number in a specific blob on GitHub) changes, readers should assume that the answer may have also changed, since the answer refers to the current state of code found at the link.